# EvaluateScriptAsync waiting in Cefsharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am having a problem about using **EvaluateScriptAsync** in Cefsharp. I want to run a javascript code with **EvaluateScriptAsync** and then, after this is completed I want my code continue to work, but **ContinueWith** isn't waiting to EvaluateScriptAsync complete. Here is my code, and don't know what's the problem:

```
private void WebBrowserFrameLoadEnded(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        var task = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { function xx() { $('body').animate({scrollTop: $('body').prop(\"scrollHeight\")}, 8000, function() { var win = $(window); if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) { return true; } else { xx(); } }); }; xx(); })();");

        task.ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
        {
            if (taskHtml.IsCompleted)
            {
                /* Some code working */
            }
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't checked to see if the script executed successfully, check the task result

Comment: @amaitland script is working, I've checked it.

Comment: Please update your code to show where your checking the response.

Answer (score -2):

You Should use the ExecuteSciptAsyc() method of the Browser Tab Control.

1st you have to get the Current tab page Control and then call the ExecuteSciptAsyc() method from browser control.

var control = GetCurrentTabControl();
            control.Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("alert('It's Working')");